# how to get the second with php?

Tags: php

Suppose an array has the following data:

```
2,test
3,example
4,test,example
```

I want to get the data:

```
test
example
test,example
```

I use `$a=explode(','$data);`, then echo `$a[1]`.

But the third one output is `test`. How to get `test,example` ?

Comment: Use `strpos` and `substr` - see their docs at php.net.

Comment: You should fully read the documentation for what a function does before you decide to use it. Your desired output is a built-in parameter to explode.

Comment: @rdlowrey thanks for putting my waffle in concise form :-)

Comment: @cbuckley Mutual comment upvote love!

Answer (score 6):

use the third parameter for explode (limiting the number of splits):

```
$a = explode(',', $data, 2);
```

---

ref: http://php.net/manual/function.explode.php

> array explode ( string $delimiter , string $string [, int $limit ] )

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach( $strings as $str)
    echo substr( $str, strpos( $str, ',') + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

The will work for you:

```
    $string='21,test,example';
    $output= explode(',', $string, 2);
    echo $output[1];//echoes test,example
```

or this:

```
echo substr($string, strpos($string, ',')+1); //echoes test,example
```

Both cases work fine.

Answer (score -1):

```
    echo substr($data, strpos($string, ",")+1);
```

Or, implode all indexes greater than 0 from your explode result.